# requests.post blocks

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I have a code to send a http post request as below.

```
header_params = {'Connection': 'close', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'content-type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.post(url, json=config_data, headers=header_params)
```

As you may notice, I am using python requests library. But this code blocks for a negligibly larger JSON and I do not see the requests hitting the server. Not sure why? any thoughts?

The JSON file is

> {"name": "DATA_POLICY_LAB_CNC4", "object_type": "Configuration",
>   "sub_type": "SDWAN_Policy_Config", "version": "1.0", "attributes":
>   {"vpn": {"TRF1": ["2000"], "TRF2": ["2001"], "INTPUB": ["301", "302"],
>   "PERMON": ["1111"], "INTPUB2": ["302"], "INTPUB3": ["303"],
>   "Bliss-All": ["301", "302", "303", "404", "1111"]}, "site":
>   {"Site_0997": ["997"]}, "tloc": {"msg": "no tloc lists configured
>   under this policyDATA_POLICY_LAB_CNC4"}, "apply": [" site-list
>   Site_0997", "  data-policy DATA_POLICY_Site_0997 from-service"],
>   "permon": ["  vpn-list PERMON", "    sequence 1", "     match", "
>   protocol 1", "      packet-length 64-95", "     !", "     action
>   accept", "      set", "       local-tloc-list ", "        color blue",
>   "        encap ipsec", "        restrict", "      !", "     !", "
>   !", "    sequence 11", "     match", "      packet-length 96-127", "
>   protocol 1", "     !", "     action accept", "      set", "
>   local-tloc-list ", "        color metro-ethernet", "        encap
>   ipsec", "        restrict", "      !", "    !", "    sequence 21", "
>   match", "      packet-length 128-159", "      protocol 1", "     !", "
>   action accept", "      set", "       local-tloc-list ", "        color
>   gold", "        encap ipsec", "        restrict", "      !", "     !",
>   "    !", "    sequence 31", "     match", "      packet-length
>   160-191", "      protocol 1", "     !", "     action accept", "
>   set", "       local-tloc-list ", "        color private1", "
>   encap gre", "        restrict", "      !", "     !", "    !", "
>   sequence 41", "     match", "      packet-length 192-223", "
>   protocol 1", "     !", "     action accept", "      set", "
>   local-tloc-list ", "        color private2", "        encap gre", "
>   restrict", "      !", "     !", "    !", "    sequence 51", "
>   match", "      packet-length 224-255", "      protocol 1", "     !", "
>   action accept", "      set", "       local-tloc-list ", "        color
>   private3", "        encap gre", "        restrict", "      !", "
>   !", "    !", "    sequence 61", "     match", "      packet-length
>   256-287", "      protocol 1", "     !", "     action accept", "
>   set", "       local-tloc-list ", "        color private4", "
>   encap gre", "        restrict", "      !", "     !", "    !", "
>   sequence 71", "     match", "      packet-length 288-319", "
>   protocol 1", "     !", "     action accept", "      set", "
>   local-tloc-list ", "        color private5", "        encap ipsec", " 
>   restrict", "      !", "     !", "    !", "    sequence 81", "
>   match", "      packet-length 320-355", "      protocol 1", "     !", "
>   action accept", "      set", "       local-tloc-list ", "        color
>   private6", "        encap ipsec", "        restrict", "      !", "
>   !", "    !", "  default-action reject", " !"], "policy":
>   {"DATA_POLICY_Site_0997": {"TRF1": [{}, {"default": "  default-action
>   accept"}], "TRF2": [{}, {"default": "   default-action accept"}],
>   "INTPUB": [{}, {"default": "   default-action accept  "}], "PERMON":
>   [{"tloc": "None", "action": "action accept"}, {"tloc": "None",
>   "action": "action accept"}, {"tloc": "None", "action": "action
>   accept"}, {"tloc": "None", "action": "action accept"}, {"tloc":
>   "None", "action": "action accept"}, {"tloc": "None", "action": "action
>   accept"}, {"tloc": "None", "action": "action accept"}, {"tloc":
>   "None", "action": "action accept"}, {"tloc": "None", "action": "action
>   accept"}, {"default": "  default-action reject"}], "INTPUB2": [{},
>   {"default": " default-action accept"}]}}, "prefix": {"msg": "no
>   subnets configured under this policyDATA_POLICY_LAB_CNC4"},
>   "policy_info": {"@rid": 1336, "policyId":
>   "e48af614-2152-4712-9135-18bc3672871b", "createdBy": "admin",
>   "createdOn": 1560988251220, "policyName": "DATA_POLICY_LAB_CNC4",
>   "policyType": "cli", "lastUpdatedBy": "admin", "lastUpdatedOn":
>   1560988251220, "policyVersion": "06032019T104041102",
>   "isPolicyActivated": false, "policyDescription":
>   "DATA_POLICY_LAB_CNC4"}, "controller_id": 2, "control_policy": ["
>   control-policy CONTROL_POLICY_Site_0997", "    sequence 10", "
>   match route", "      site-list Site_0997", "      vpn-list Bliss-All",
>   "     action accept", "    sequence 20", "     match tloc", "
>   site-list Site_0997", "     action accept", "      set", "
>   preference 20", "  default-action reject", " !", "!"],
>   "target_controller_type": "REMOTE"}}

Comment: I dont think that;s the correct json format - please check it here - https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Yes, I verified that. Perhaps here it may look like it is not correct because of the formatting. But that was the first thing I verified. All is well with JSON format

Comment: Somethime the server takes hits only from web browsers, so modify your header as - header_params = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0','Connection': 'close', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'content-type': 'application/json'}

Comment: Yes, I came across this suggestion and tried. It did not work.

Comment: What else have you already tried (so there is no point in suggesting)?

Comment: I suspect the it has got to do with the size of the json file. Same code works for a smaller json objects. I am not able to verify it though!